# How to unit test a transaction commit timeout in MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions, commit

I'm writing a unit test to reproduce the scenario where a timeout is reached when calling Commit on a MySqlTransaction (using C# and MySql Connector/Net), but I just don't find the way to force this kind of timeout. All of my tests will only provoke delays when doing the ExecuteNonQuery call on the command, but no delays ever happen once it hits transacion.Commit().

Is there any way to force a timeout on a commit?

Comment: I would try to lock some data, but I guess it depends on the dbtype you selected. Anybody to confirm ?

Comment: Any sample code on the data locking would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be easier and appropriate to mock the Commit method to simulate a timeout instead of trying to force it?

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that you are writing an integration test, if you try to get the server to raise the exception?

If you want a UNIT TEST you should stub & mock all communcation with the outside world -- also you MySqlServer. If you do that, you get the bonus of being able to raise timeouts and other exceptions at will. Further, you will eliminate the risk of unittests changing/destroying data integrity in you database.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm aware of that. Any sample code you could share with me? I'm not sure how to mock this scenario.